# What's difference between HDInsight Hadoop cluster & HDInsight Spark cluster?

Tags: azure-hdinsight

What's difference between HDInsight Hadoop cluster & HDInsight Spark cluster? I have seen that even in Hadoop cluster pyspark is available. Is the difference with respect to the cluster type? i.e. Hadoop cluster implies YARN as a cluster management layer and Spark implying Spark Standalone (or Mesos?) as a cluster management layer?

If that is the case we can still run Spark in Hadoop cluster I believe so Spark will run on top of YARN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bits are the same as you noticed. The difference is set of services and Ambari components that are running by default (on Spark you will have additional spark thrift, livy, jupyter) and set of configurations for those services. So while you technically can run spark jobs on yarn on hadoop cluster it's not recommended, some configs may be not set to optimal values. The other way around would be more reliable - create spark cluster and run hadoop jobs on it.

Maxim (HDInsight Spark PM)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But one thing is not made explicitly clear from your answer -- are you saying that HDInsight Spark does not use YARN as a cluster management layer? If not, which one does it use? Mesos or Spark Standalone?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-overview#:~:text=The%20SparkContext%20can%20connect%20to,using%20the%20YARN%20cluster%20manager. According to this document by Azure, HDI uses YARN as the cluster manager.

Answer (score 3):

HDInsight Spark uses YARN as cluster management layer, just as Hadoop. The binary on the cluster is the same.

The difference between HDInsight Spark and Hadoop clusters are the following:

1) Optimal Configurations: 
Spark cluster is tuned and configured for spark workloads. For example, we have pre-configured spark clusters to use SSD and adjust executor memory size based on machine resource, so customers will have better out-of-box experience than the spark default configuration.

2) Service setups:
Spark cluster also run spark-related services including Livy, Jupyter, and Spark Thrift Server.

3)Workload Quality: We test spark workloads on spark clusters prior every release to ensure quality of service.